# Why do we use two ways to write the kinetic term in a Lagrangian?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, conventions, path-integral

I have just started reading Schwartz's book on QFT and I see from the first few chapters that he writes the kinetic part of the Lagrangian in a way I find strange.

As an example, for the massless scalar field he writes it as:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{K} = \frac{1}{2}\phi\Box\phi
\end{equation}

I get that I can rewrite this in the "normal" way plus a four-divergence that vanishes when we vary the action, such that the equations of motion remain invariant.

My question is *why do we write the Lagrangian in this form?*

I did skim a bit ahead in the book and saw that in the path integral chapter this seems like a convenient way to have the Lagrangian such that the we can compute the generating functional by just using the formula for the Gaussian integrals. Is this the only reason?

Comment: Another reason is that with this description the (derivative part of the) equations of motion follow(s) immediately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct starting point is always$^1$
$$ S~=~\frac{1}{2}\int\! d^4x \left( \mp\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi  + \ldots \right)
~=~\frac{1}{2}\int\! d^4x \left( \dot{\phi}^2 + \ldots \right),\tag{1}$$
since the kinetic term should be positive definite. When authors write
$$ S~=~\frac{1}{2}\int\! d^4x \left( \pm \phi\Box\phi + \ldots\right)
~=~\frac{1}{2}\int\! d^4x \left( - \phi\ddot{\phi} + \ldots\right) ,\tag{2}$$
it is because they have integrated (1) by parts.
(This fact also apply to other fields than a scalar field $\phi$.)

If we want to study extended field configurations, like solitons, etc, we cannot drop boundary terms. However, for many other applications$^1$ in field theory, the boundary terms vanish, so that (1) reduces to (2).

TL;DR: Why do authors write (2) instead of (1)? Answer: Convenience.

--

$^1$ It should be stressed that for certain tasks, such as, e.g.,

1. finding the [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) of the action, or
2. in order for $\Box$ to be a [self-adjoint operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator),

it is important to impose appropriate boundary conditions (BC).

Comment: Although I am glad this was helpful to the OP, this is not an answer to the question. "Why do we write the Lagrangian in this form?" -> "Because we have integrated by parts."

Comment: The answer I understood is the "convenience" part. Since in the context of the QFT book by Schwartz (at least in the earlier chapters) the boundary terms vanish, it's convenient to write the Lagrangians this way since it's easier to evaluate Gaussian integrals involving the action. I think you get the same result even if you don't work with this way of writing the Lagrangian as long as the fields vanish at the boundary.